# NSTableView error: preparedCellAtColumn:row: was Called

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I'm having an issue where when you select a top level object in an NSOutlineView, an error message is generated saying:

> "View Based NSTableView error: preparedCellAtColumn:row: was called. Please log a bug with the backtrace from this log, or stop using the method."

The NSOutlineView I am using is set to View Based.  I have no idea why the preparedCellAtColumn method is even being called.  I added the method and placed a breakpoint to try and trace what is calling it, but XCode looks to be blocking the execution of it when it fires this exception.

**Edit - Delegate and DateSource Methods**

```
- (BOOL) itemAtIndexIsHeader: (NSInteger) index
{
    return [self isHeader: [_projectPane itemAtRow: index]];
}
- (BOOL) isHeader: (id) item
{
    return [item isKindOfClass: [Folder class]];
}
- (BOOL) outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isGroupItem:(id)item
{
    return NO;
}
- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item
{
    //item is nil when the outline view wants to inquire for root level items
    if (item == nil)
        return [[[PMDataManager sharedManager] allFolders] objectAtIndex: index];
    else{
        Folder *folder = (Folder *) item;
        return [[[folder projects] allObjects] objectAtIndex: index];
    }
}
- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item
{
    return [self isHeader: item];
}
- (NSInteger)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView numberOfChildrenOfItem:(id)item
{
    if (item == nil) { //item is nil when the outline view wants to inquire for root level items
        return [[[PMDataManager sharedManager] allFolders] count];
    }
    else if ([self isHeader: item]) {
        Folder *folder = (Folder *) item;
        return [[[folder projects] allObjects] count];
    }

    return 0;
}
- (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item {
    if ([self isHeader: item]){
        PMProjectHeaderCell *cell = [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"HeaderCell" owner:self];
        Folder *folder = (Folder *) item;
        [[cell headerText] setStringValue: [folder name]];

        return cell;
    }
    else{
        PMProjectCell *cell = [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"ProjectCell" owner:self];
        Project *project = (Project *) item;
        [[cell projectNameTextField] setStringValue: [project name]];
        return cell;
    }

    return nil;
}
- (void) outlineViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    selectedProjectIndex = [_projectPane selectedRow];
    [self reloadRightPane];
    [self refresh: nil];
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your `NSOutlineViewDataSource` and `NSOutlineViewDelegate` method implementations.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am encountering the same issue.

Comment: I did not, as far as I can tell this is a long time bug that is not yet resolved.  From what I have read, you don't have to fix this, you just have to deal with the error (pretty annoying, but really doesn't harm anything).

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your table view content mode matches the datasource/delegate methods you are trying to use.

If you're trying to use cell-based datasource, verify that the table view content mode is "Cell Based". The same for view based.